# Mount FTP using GVFS at the command-line

Tags: d-bus, gvfs

I am on Debian Jessie without desktop environment. I try to mount an FTP by command line using gvfs-mount.

I gathered information on the web and I understood that gvfs comunicates with dbus.

So my first step was to **install dbus and gvfs required packages** :

```
apt-get install dbus-x11 gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse
```

Then I reboot, because dbus installed its own service.

After that, I am logging in as www-data

```
sudo -Hu www-data -s /bin/bash
```

(`-s /bin/bash` is because this user has no bash)

From here, I have to launch a `dbus-daemon` for my user and export the resulting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in order for gvfs to communicate with that daemon. So I do:

```
dbus-launch --sh-syntax > "$HOME/.dbus_settings"
```

`.dbus_settings` contains something like:

```
cat .dbus_settings 
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-XwbyV2BmA5,guid=6c111d728c263543b61e6293570e1f22';
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS;
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=952;
```

My environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is not set at this time, so I run:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-XwbyV2BmA5,guid=6c111d728c263543b61e6293570e1f22'
```

In order to handle future gvfs mounts, I created a `.gvfs` folder in my user `$HOME` (for www-data it is `/var/www`)

Now, I think (but I am not sure) I have all set to use gvfs. so I launch **gvfsd-fuse** like this:

```
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse $HOME/.gvfs -o big_writes
```

That seems to work. The folder $HOME/.gvfs appears to be mounted (but there is nothing in it yet).

The last command is the effective FTP mount:

```
gvfs-mount ftp://myftpuser@myftpserver < file_containing_ftp_password
```

But, I always get this error:

```
Error mounting location: Location is not mountable
```

These steps work on my Linux Mint 17.3 amd64 desktop. But I cannot make it work on a Debian Jessie server (without desktop and x11).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem. A package was missing `gvfs-backends` and some commands was useless.

To resume, the steps are :

1. Install necessary packages:

   apt-get install dbus-x11 gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse gvfs-backends
2. Create .gvfs folder if it does not exist

   mkdir $HOME/.gvfs
3. Start a dbus session and store `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to be able to re-use it

   dbus-launch --sh-syntax > "$HOME/.dbus_settings"
4. export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` using `source` for example

   source "$HOME/.dbus_settings"
5. Simply mount it with gvfs-mount

   gvfs-mount ftp://myftpuser@myftpserver

Shell will prompt for your password. You can also create a file containing your password and give it to gvfs-mount so that the command will be:

```
gvfs-mount ftp://myftpuser@myftpserver < file_containing_my_ftp_password
```

6. Access your mounted FTP at this place:

   cd $HOME/.gvfs/ftp:host\=myftpserver\,user\=myftpuser/

Done !

Comment: Worked for me, but the mount was located at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`

Comment: It seems `gvfs-mount` has been deprecated in favor of `gio mount`: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=275682 (They otherwise would behave the same.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use `dbus-run-session some-script.sh`,
then you can call `gio mount` or other gio tool inside `some-script.sh`.

dbus-run-session will kill dbus-daemon after script execution,
or you need to manual kill dbus-daemon if you use `dbus-launch` .

It would be little troublesome to use dbus-run-session
because you need to write another script and call it with
command dbus-run-session.

You can do like:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sed '1,/^exit$/d' $0 | dbus-run-session sh
exit

ftp_url=ftp://root@0.0.0.0/
ftp_password=password
echo $ftp_password | gio mount $ftp_url

ftp_gio_name=$(
    gio info $ftp_url | awk '$1 == "id::filesystem:" { print $2 }'
)
ftp_gio_path=$HOME/.gvfs/"$ftp_gio_name"
archive_path=$HOME/data

cp --archive --verbose --update \
   "$ftp_gio_path"/ \
   $archive_path

gio mount -u $ftp_url
```

or use tail:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
tail +4 $0 | dbus-run-session sh
exit

# script here
```

or use heredoc:

```bsh
dbus-run-session sh <<DBUS_SESSION

# script here
# but you need to escape $ and \

foo=bar
echo \$foo
touch white\\ space

DBUS_SESSION
```